# Populating a Datagridview ComboBox from the results of the other comboboxes

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I currently have a datagridview that consists of 3 drop down boxes

1) Unit To
2) Unit From
3) Product Name

Unit To and Unit From are populated from the database.

However, I want the Product combobox to populate with products that are available in the selected unit to and unit from.

The SQL statement isn't the issue here - I am just unsure at which event this would come under.

The SQL would be something like

```
    SELECT ApprovedProductForUnit.[Product Name]
    FROM ApprovedProductForUnit
    WHERE (((ApprovedProductForUnit.[Unit No])='301' Or (ApprovedProductForUnit.[Unit No])='308'))
    GROUP BY ApprovedProductForUnit.[Product Name]
    HAVING Count(ApprovedProductForUnit.[Unit No])> 1
```

I would like to know where to insert the SQL statement to populate the Product Name gridviewcombobox this would also need to include the possibility of the user changing either the unit to or unit from. Of course the value would change on each row which is dependant on Products that are being sold in both units.

Comment: Basically are you trying to convert from one unit to another?

Comment: What I am doing is when a user selects a unit from and a unit to it runs the SQL command above and populates the product name combobox with the results.

Comment: You have to write the code in unit to onchange even which will pass both unit to and unit from id's to the sql query. Hope this helps.

Comment: Im aware I need to do this but I'm simply unsure where the code needs to go, the comboboxes don't have events so how would i do this.

Comment: I am pretty sure that these comboboxes have events. But you can access them programitically. May be a simple google search will be enough to find out how to use the events from the datagrid combo boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to populate the Product Name gridviewcombobox in the Unit To combobox **OnChange** event, similarly for the Unit From combobox. In both cases, you would have to check whether 'the other' combobox has a value, which suggests that both OnChange events should call a common procedure which checks values and then populates the Product Name combobox.

I think that the 'having' clause in the SQL is unnecessary and could lead to wrong results.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, The issues I am having is that none of the comboboxes seems to allow events.
The sql Statement has been tested in access and seems to do what I need it to.

Comment: I program in Delphi so I'm used to seeing comboboxes with events.